# Is there a general way to get a themes primary colour?

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development

I'm writing a plugin and I'd like it to play nicely with wordpress themes by adopting the themes colour schemes.
To be specific, not just use a HTML element that was incidentally styled by a themes CSS but to actually get at the themes colour scheme to, for example, set a border colour on a custom element to follow the themes primary colour.

Is this possible, or do all themes save their config differently?

I seen mention of get_theme_mod($propertyName) - but is that propertyName defined by the theme author?
I've seen other plugins advertised to follow a themes style - how do they do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to follow the "theme style" is not to add CSS of your own.

There is really no such thing as "theme color scheme" and if there was, it might be hard coded.